# sql query to fetch the one value from table if we have same value saved twice

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

i need to find a record from a table and if record already exist than only one record will be shown (i cannot use DISTINCT)

for example if there are 2 value in table www.google.com and another will be google.com/testing

so my query should be like that it will get display only either of any values. 
if there is no way to get using sql than how we can achieve using php function. following is my code

```
   `$qry_linkurl="SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='links_url'";
    $result_option= $wpdb->get_results($qry_linkurl,ARRAY_A);
    $p=array();
    foreach($result_option as $key=>$value){
    $query = "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='links_url' and meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%', SUBSTR('".$value['meta_value']."', 1, 18), '%')";
   $result= $wpdb->get_results($query,ARRAY_A);
   $p[]=$resul['meta_value'];
  }`
```

Comment: `$qry_linkurl="SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='links_url' LIMIT 1";`

Comment: but the meta_value can be more than 1 ..
there might be another meta_value =facebook.com and another saved with name :- facebook.com/testing
 than how can i get "google.com" and "facebook.com"  from the result

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
MYSQL:

SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='links_url' ORDER BY meta_value LIMIT 1

SQL SERVER:

SELECT TOP 1 meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='links_url' ORDER BY meta_value
```

Comment: but the meta_value can be more than 1 .. there might be another meta_value =facebook.com and another saved with name :- facebook.com/testing than how can i get "google.com" and "facebook.com" from the result

Comment: Do you mean for a single meta_key you would have two distinct meta_values one is google.com and the other is facebook.com.

Comment: i mean in meta_values we can have values like:- google.com, google.com/testing, facebook.com, facebook.com/testing  where meta_keys='links_url'  and I need to fetch only one among the similar domain like
 my result should show google.com and facebook.com only

Comment: Have you tested my query what it returned based on your data. Tell me what you get and what you are expecting in the query I posted

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='links_url' order by id desc limit 0,1;
```

You will be getting latest record.

Comment: i donot need latest one record.. i need to display same record only once

Comment: SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='links_url' limit 0,1;

Comment: but the meta_value can be more than 1 .. there might be another meta_value =facebook.com and another saved with name :- facebook.com/testing than how can i get "google.com" and "facebook.com" from the
result
please check my code i have updated